# MenuItem with onClick={popupState.close} in Material-ui V 5.0 how to execute a Link to open the component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, material-ui

Hi folks after spending the hole sunday trying to make a dropdown menu at the AppBar menu, I got all types of errors. The only menu that a could run without breaking the application was with "PopupState helper" https://mui.com/material-ui/react-menu/#basic-menu.
My question is how to implement a link to redirect to the selected component to execute the functions. Is it clear? On the code bellow will get clear enough. The problem is that onClick closes the menu, and I could'n include any ".newFunction", because it don't close.
I'm accepting other suggestions to make a dropdown menu at the toolBar that works.

```js
 <AppBar className={classes.appbar} elevation={1} position="fixed">    
            
                <Toolbar style={ { margimleft: 1000 }}  width="1250px" className="toolbar">
                    <Typography className={classes.date} ml={3}>
                        Bem Vindo ao CashFlowBR - Hoje:  {format(new Date(), 'do MMMM Y')}
                    </Typography>
                   {/* sx={{ bgcolor: "#1483dd", color: "#ffffff", mr: 2, mt: 1 }} */}
                   <PopupState variant="popover" popupId="demo-popup-menu">
                        {(popupState) => (
                          <React.Fragment>
                            <Button variant="text" {...bindTrigger(popupState)}
                            sx={{ bgcolor: "#1483dd", color: "#ffffff", mr: 3, mt: 1 }}
                            >
                              Consultas
                            </Button>
                            <Menu {...bindMenu(popupState)}>
                              <MenuItem onClick={popupState.close.newFunction}>Títulos a Pagar</MenuItem> // doesn't work
                              <MenuItem onClick={popupState.close}>Títulos a Receber</MenuItem>
                              <Divider color="#616161" mt={1} /> 
                              <MenuItem onClick={popupState.close}>Lançamentos Bancários</MenuItem>
                              <Divider color="#616161" mt={1} /> 
                              <MenuItem onClick={popupState.close}>Títulos Pagos</MenuItem>
                              <MenuItem onClick={popupState.close}>Títulos Recebidos</MenuItem>
                            </Menu>
                          </React.Fragment>
                        )}
                  </PopupState>
                    
                                  
                   {/* Final */}
                    <Button
                        id="basic-button"
                        aria-controls={open ? 'basic-menu' : undefined}
                        aria-haspopup="true"
                        aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
                        // onClick={handleClickAppBarReports}
                        sx={{ bgcolor: "#1483dd", color: "#ffffff", mr: 23, mt: 1 }}
                    >
                      Relatórios
                    </Button>
                    <Typography mr={4}>
                        Login
                    </Typography>
                </Toolbar>

            </AppBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi folks after a long search I found a solution for this question:

your text here

This is working pretty fine to me. Material ui - V. 5.0.

The answer I found in this link: look at goyney's post.
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/204

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).